# SSH with Yubikey and intermediate host

Tags: ssh, debian, mac-osx, smartcard

I'm on macos with a Yubikey. The Yubikey's publickey is added to ServerA and ServerB. I can connect to any server directly from macos with the Yubikey plugged in.

Is it possible to SSH to ServerA and from there to ServerB like so:

```
macos -> ServerA -> ServerB
```

This does not work out of the box because the publikey of user@ServerA is not known on ServerB.

Is it possible to have ServerA use the Yubikey that is plugged into the mac when connecting to ServerB via SSH?

Comment: I don't understand the bit about the public key not being known but it sounds like you're looking for `man ssh`, particularly the `-J` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Agent forwarding (-A)

   ```
   $ ssh -A ServerA
   [ServerA] $ ssh ServerB
   ```
2. ProxyJump (-J)

   ```
   $ ssh -J ServerA ServerB
   ```

I've used both of these with gpg-agent and Yubikey.

Comment: I vote for the ProxyJump option. It's simpler (especially if you put it in ~/.ssh/config on the client), works transparently with `scp` and `sftp`, and doesn't expose anything other than encrypted connection on ServerA (just in case that's been exploited somehow).